# overload and override which throws exception

Tags: java, overriding, overloading, throw

```
   public class A {
        public float foo(float a, float b) throws IOException {
  }
}
    public class B extends A  {
           ......
    }
```

Which functions can be placed in B class, and why?

> 1. float foo(float a, float b){...}
> 2. public int foo (int a, int b) throws Exception {...}
> 3. public float foo(float a, float b) throws Exception {...}
> 4. public float foo(float p, float q) {...}

my opinion: 1. wrong, doesn't start with public 2. correct, overloading 3. wrong, overriding can't throw broader exception 4. wrong, overriding can't throw broader exception

Comment: What exactly do you ask? By the way, choice *2* is wrong too, as you cannot overload a function by changing its return type.

Comment: @PiXel1225: You can't overload a method by *only* changing its return type. You can change the return type and parameter types as well though.

Comment: @ PiXel1225 : 2 is correct, look at the input type

Comment: 4 is wrong too since the declared Exceptions are not the same.

Comment: You are right, missed the parameters.

Comment: @f1sh: maybe 4 is correct, the fact that there isn't any throw of exception may be ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general principle governing what is allowed or not in an override is that you can't break Java's ability to use an instance of the subclass in a context where the declared type is the supertype.

```
 float foo(float a, float b){...}
```

Incorrect because you cannot *reduce* the visibility of the method in the subclass.  (If it was allowed, what would happen at runtime if someone called `foo` on `a` declared as `A a = new B();` ?)

```
 public int foo (int a, int b) throws Exception {...}
```

Correct.

If this was an override, it would be incorrect because you can't use an incompatible return type.  (You *can* change the return type, but the return type in the override must be a subtype of the return type in the overridden)

However, since the argument types are different, this is an overload, not an override ... and it is correct!

```
 public float foo (float a, float) throws Exception {...}
```

Incorrect because you cannot throw a broader (checked) exception.  You can *change* the exception(s) but they must be subtype exceptions in the subclass.  (The point is that the subclass method must not be allowed to throw checked exceptions that the superclass methods signature says can't be thrown.)

```
public float foo(float p, float q) {...}
```

Correct.  An override method can omit thrown exception declarations that are thrown in the overridden method.  (It doesn't break the checked exception rules if the subclass method *can't* throw and exception that the superclass method could.)

Comment: about "float foo(float a, float b){...}", why did you say the visibility is reduced? isn't it public by default (if nothing were written?)?

Comment: No.  The default visibility is "package private" which is more restrictive than `public`.

Comment: @  Stephen C, thak you again!! "package private" with no importance of the class it belongs to?

Comment: The method override rules are independent of class access, though (obviously) it is not legal to create a subclass in a context where the superclass is not visible to the subclass.